# Enable mDNS within buildroot

Tags: buildroot, mdns, avahi

I have a working buildroot build (2017.02.1). I need to add mDNS.
Using the configuration menu I managed to add and build the first avahi auto ip option. 
When I add the mDNS and libdns_sd sub options the build fails (below). 
I have removed 'dbus' from 'fs_skeleton/etc/passwd' but the build still fails.
I am new to buildroot & so any pointers would help!

```
mkdir -p /home/user/buildroot-mywork/buildroot/output/target/etc
( \
    echo "NAME=Buildroot"; \
    echo "VERSION=2017.02.1-00039-g464795e"; \
    echo "ID=buildroot"; \
    echo "VERSION_ID=2017.02.1"; \
    echo "PRETTY_NAME=\"Buildroot 2017.02.1\"" \
) >  /home/user/buildroot-mywork/buildroot/output/target/etc/os-release
>>>   Copying overlay /home/user/buildroot-mywork/buildroot/../target/device/myproduct_mx6/production/rootfs_overlay
>>>   Executing post-build script /home/user/buildroot-mywork/buildroot/../target/device/myproduct_mx6/production/postbuild.sh
!*!*!*[ POST BUILD ]*!*!*!
>>>   Generating root filesystem image rootfs.tar
rm -f /home/user/buildroot-mywork/buildroot/output/build/_fakeroot.fs
rm -f /home/user/buildroot-mywork/buildroot/output/target/THIS_IS_NOT_YOUR_ROOT_FILESYSTEM
rm -f /home/user/buildroot-mywork/buildroot/output/build/_users_table.txt
echo '#!/bin/sh' > /home/user/buildroot-mywork/buildroot/output/build/_fakeroot.fs
echo "set -e" >> /home/user/buildroot-mywork/buildroot/output/build/_fakeroot.fs
echo "chown -h -R 0:0 /home/user/buildroot-mywork/buildroot/output/target" >> /home/user/buildroot-mywork/buildroot/output/build/_fakeroot.fs
printf '    avahi -1 avahi -1 * - - -\n     dbus -1 dbus -1 * /var/run/dbus - dbus DBus messagebus user\n   mosquitto -1 nogroup -1 * - - - Mosquitto user\n    sshd -1 sshd -1 * - - - SSH drop priv user\n\n' >> /home/user/buildroot-mywork/buildroot/output/build/_users_table.txt
PATH="/opt/buildroot-2017.02.1/bin:/opt/buildroot-2017.02.1/sbin:/opt/buildroot-2017.02.1/usr/bin:/opt/buildroot-2017.02.1/usr/sbin:/home/user/bin:/home/user/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin" /home/user/buildroot-mywork/buildroot/support/scripts/mkusers /home/user/buildroot-mywork/buildroot/output/build/_users_table.txt /home/user/buildroot-mywork/buildroot/output/target >> /home/user/buildroot-mywork/buildroot/output/build/_fakeroot.fs
mkusers: user 'dbus' already exists with group 'avahi' (wants 'dbus')
fs/tar/tar.mk:14: recipe for target '/home/user/buildroot-mywork/buildroot/output/images/rootfs.tar' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/user/buildroot-mywork/buildroot/output/images/rootfs.tar] Error 1
Makefile:79: recipe for target '_all' failed
make[1]: *** [_all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/buildroot-mywork/buildroot'
Makefile:120: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
user@SDKQ:~/buildroot-mywork$
```

_user_table.txt:

```
avahi -1 avahi -1 * - - -
dbus -1 dbus -1 * /var/run/dbus - dbus DBus messagebus user
mosquitto -1 nogroup -1 * - - - Mosquitto user
sshd -1 sshd -1 * - - - SSH drop priv user
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks weird. Please report this bug to the Buildroot bug tracker, after making sure:
 1/ That you can reproduce after a completely clean build (`make clean all`)
 2/ That you include a Buildroot .config file that allows to reproduce the problem.